# How to display another sites RSS feed in my ASP.NET site?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I easily did this in SharePoint, but I can't seem to figure out how to do so in ASP.NET. I just want to display some simple RSS feeds within my site from websites such as Weather.com (http://www.weather.com/rss/national/rss_nwf_rss.xml?cm_ven=NWF&cm_cat=rss&par=NWF_rss). At every example I look at they keep connecting to databases and adding all this extra stuff that seems frivolous. Surely there has to be an easy way to add your URL and bind to a Listview/Gridview to display the data. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a repeater to populate items from RSS and also use Syndication (System.ServiceModel.Syndication). I have chosen repeater because it has very flexible layout. You can use ListView or GridView if you wish. My markup would look like this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptRSS" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptRSS_ItemDataBound">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table class="tablerss">
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td class="rsstitle">
                <asp:Label ID="lblRSSTitle" runat="server" CssClass="rsshead"></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkArticle" runat="server"></asp:HyperLink>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="rssdescription">
                <asp:Label ID="lblDescription" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
                    <br />
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And in my code I have:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        LoadRSS();
    }
}
protected void rptRSS_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        HyperLink lnkArticle = (HyperLink)e.Item.FindControl("lnkArticle");
        Label lblDescription = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblDescription");
        Label lblRSSTitle = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblRSSTitle");
        SyndicationItem item = (SyndicationItem)e.Item.DataItem;

        lnkArticle.Text = item.Title.Text;
        lnkArticle.NavigateUrl = item.Links[0].Uri.ToString(); ;
        lblRSSTitle.Text = item.Title.Text;
        lblDescription.Text = item.Summary.Text;
    }
}

private void LoadRSS()
{                
    List<SyndicationItem> lstSynItem = new List<SyndicationItem>();
    string uri = "http://www.weather.com/rss/national/rss_nwf_rss.xml?cm_ven=NWF&cm_cat=rss&par=NWF_rss";
    SyndicationFeed myRss = SyndicationFeed.Load(XmlReader.Create(uri));

    foreach (SyndicationItem item in myRss.Items)
    {
        lstSynItem.Add(item);
    }
    rptRSS.DataSource = lstSynItem;
    rptRSS.DataBind();
}
```

There are some good articles by [Scott Michell](https://web.archive.org/web/20110303000025/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com:80/ScottMitchell.shtml), although they were not updated, but still helps to start exploring RSS!